# Unexpected identifier when using import abc = require('node-module')

Tags: node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have a .ts file

```
import abc = require('abc'); // example
module.exports = { ...
execute(test : abc.class ,args : Array<string>) { ...
```

When i run the code, IDE sends error:

```
import abc = require('abc');
       ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

I cant using const abc = require('abc'), because https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5ueG.jpg
And Module '"abc"' has no default export.ts(1192)

Comment: you're mixing `import` and `require`. Use one or the other.

Comment: like @NikKyriakides said, your mixing imopoer with require.
use it: import * as abc from 'abc'.
or const abc = require('abc')

Comment: Module '"abc"' has no default export.ts(1192)

Comment: How does your export in module `abc` look like?

Comment: ^^ `import = require` is [valid TS syntax](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require), @OP: make sure your IDE treats the file as Typescript, not Javascript

Comment: "*When i run the code*" - did you compile it before running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In typescript you should use
`import {abc} from 'abc' //if no export default`

`{abc}` refers to whatever you've exported.

If the export is default you can simply use:
`import randomName from 'abc' //if export default`

you can name your import anything if the export is default.

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token {